# OpenGL Application console not closing

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, terminate

I am using Visual Studio Community and I am trying to create OpenGL application.
I am using GLFW to open a window like this:

```
int main() {
    //Init stuff
    int width = 1920;


    int height = 1080;
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create Window du schmok" << std::endl;

        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "Glew was not initialized du schmok" << std::endl;
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    VertexBuffer vbo(vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    IndexBuffer ibo(indices, 6);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I have abstracted the index buffer and the vertex buffer into classes that look like this:
Vertex Buffer:

```
VertexBuffer::VertexBuffer(float data[], unsigned int size)
{
    GL_CALL(glGenBuffers(1, &m_ID));
    GL_CALL(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ID));
    GL_CALL(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW));
}

VertexBuffer::~VertexBuffer()
{
    GL_CALL(glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_ID));
}

void VertexBuffer::Bind()
{
    GL_CALL(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ID));
}

void VertexBuffer::Unbind()
{
    GL_CALL(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0));
}
```

and the Index Buffer:

```
IndexBuffer::IndexBuffer(unsigned int indices[], unsigned int count)
{
    m_Count = count;
    GL_CALL(glGenBuffers(1, &m_ID));
    GL_CALL(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ID));
    GL_CALL(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Count * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW));
}

IndexBuffer::~IndexBuffer()
{
    GL_CALL(glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_ID));
}

void IndexBuffer::Bind()
{
    GL_CALL(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ID));
}

void IndexBuffer::Unbind()
{
    GL_CALL(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0));
}
```

The problem is that after closing the window the console stays open and blinks waiting. I can only terminate the program with Visual Studio or by closing the console manually.
I have experimented with the code and it is because of the two lines where I create the objects for my buffers:
Without these two lines it works. Does anyone have an idea why that is?

Comment: I know that option. However I dont get the text "press any key to close". It simply blinking and can only be closed with visual studios debugger or the Close Button. But if I press the close button I also get a return code != 0.

Comment: It fails on both lines. I commentet both out. Then just one and then the other one. Both lines if they are left in the program give me the result I descriped.

Comment: The thing is, you never use vbo or ibo in the code, so I think now that it must be in the destructor. Is this delete buffer call correct? Is m_id maybe the same number for Vertex and Index buffer?

Comment: One problem definitely is, that the destructors are called after the OpenGL context has been deleted. At that point calling any OpenGL command will be problematic. Not sure if this causes the program to stay open.

Comment: @BDL The thing is I alos tried deleting them manually wihtout relying on the destructors. It still wouldnt work. Is there something like glew_destroy? Maybe I am not correctly destroying the context or I dont know.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I am not using them because I didnt just wann paste all my code in here and left some out because ohterwise it would have been to long.

Comment: @Nicky yes that is ok. Can you tell me what m_ID is of both (I guess they are the same). The destructor call of both seems to be the problem, so that means the second GLDeleteBuffers call could be a problem (because of the same m_ID maybe?)

Comment: @Nicky: Whats the definition of GL_CALL? Sure that it doesn't loop until no errors are returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [OpenGL Application does not terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551273/opengl-application-does-not-terminate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, the problem comes from the destruction of your buffers : the program tries to call `glDestroyX` (in buffers destructors) after the OpenGL context was destroyed, which throws errors that `GL_Call` tries to handle using GL context so it also throws error itself and so on.

To solve that, declare and use your buffers inside of a scope, and destroy GL the context after the end of the scope, so that your GL objects are destroyed *before* the GL context is destroyed.

Comment: That actually solves it although looks ugly it works.